# how to sort python list in a way that if 1 should come before and 10 and 2 before 20

Tags: python

```
['2', '8', '2', '3', '6', '4', '1', '1', '10', '6', '3', '3', '6', '1', '3', '8', '4', '6', '1', '10', '8', '4', '10', '4', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '6', '1', '5', '2', '9', '8', '5', '10', '8', '7', '9', '6', '4', '2', '6', '3', '8', '8', '9', '8', '2', '9', '10', '3', '10', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '5', '1', '4', '7', '6', '1', '10', '5', '4', '8', '4', '2', '7', '8', '1', '1', '7', '4', '1', '1', '9', '8', '6', '5', '9', '9', '3', '7', '6', '3', '10', '8', '10', '7', '2', '5', '1', '1', '9', '9', '5']
```

**after using lambda function inf following way:**

```
    a.sort(key=lambda a: int(a.split()[0]))
    a = a[::-1]
```

**I got**

```
['10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

But i want 
   10 in end after 1 , likewise if put 20 and 2 in list than 2 should come before 20 and 20 before 10 etc

Comment: Why are you calling `split()`?

Comment: i want to compare only first digit, i-e  if i input 10 and 9 than 9 should come before 10 ,

Comment: Try `print('12'.split())`. It splits on whitespace unless you provide some delimiter. You could use `list()` to break the string into individual characters (I'm not suggesting this is the correct approach here, just a side clarification)

Comment: Can you clarify what is the expected output ?

Comment: what would do? can it put 1 before 10 and 2 before 20?

Comment: @gogaz i want to sort list in a way that , it should sort only looking at first digit and if  list has 1 and 10 than 1  should get preference and 2 should have preference over 20 and so on.

Comment: still would be much better if you just showed what the output you want would actually look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an ordered list of strings. Those strings are representations of numbers. Now you want a grouped sorting. First everything that starts with a `'9'`, then `'8'` and down to `'1'`. In each of those groups the values should be sorted in numeric order.

An example list:

```
a = ['11', '105', '2', '8', '2', '3', '6', '4', '1', '1', '10', '81', '3', '3', '5', '10', '8', '7', '9', '6', '4', '2']
```

Now let's do a grouped sorting with `a.sort(key=lambda v: v[0])`:

```
['11', '105', '1', '1', '10', '10', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6', '6', '7', '8', '81', '8', '9']
```

We see, that the values are grouped now, but we want the values starting with `'9'` first. We're going to fix this by reversing the result with `a.sort(key=lambda v: v[0], reversed=True)`

```
['9', '8', '81', '8', '7', '6', '6', '5', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '11', '105', '1', '1', '10', '10']
```

The groups are correct, now we have to sort the values in the groups. So after the sorting according to the first character we have to sort the value by number. That's easy, we just have to create a `tuple` for the key: `a.sort(key=lambda v: (v[0], int(v)), reverse=True)`

```
['9', '81', '8', '8', '7', '6', '6', '5', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '105', '11', '10', '10', '1', '1']
```

OK, the values are sorted now, but we have to reverse them in the groups. The easiest way to do that ist to take the negative number: `a.sort(key=lambda v: (v[0], -int(v)), reverse=True)`.

```
['9', '8', '8', '81', '7', '6', '6', '5', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '10', '10', '11', '105']
```

Comment: Thanks Dear, it helped  me to get expected result

Answer (score 1):

The operation:

```
a.sort()
```

with no other options sets `a` to:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following sample using `key=str`

```
   integers = ['2', '8', '2', '3', '6', '4', '1', '1', '10', '6', '3', '3', '6', '1', '3', '8', '4', '6', '1', '10', '8', '4', '10', '4', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '6', '1', '5', '2', '9', '8', '5', '10', '8', '7', '9', '6', '4', '2', '6', '3', '8', '8', '9', '8', '2', '9', '10', '3', '10', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '5', '1', '4', '7', '6', '1', '10', '5', '4', '8', '4', '2', '7', '8', '1', '1', '7', '4', '1', '1', '9', '8', '6', '5', '9', '9', '3', '7', '6', '3', '10', '8', '10', '7', '2', '5', '1', '1', '9', '9', '5']

    print(sorted(integers, key=str))
```

Comment: let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use lambda method here. Instead of using lambda you can use '.sort()' method to sort the items in the list. like this one:

```
li=['2', '8', '2', '3', '6', '4', '1', '1', '10', '6', '3', '3', '6', '1', '3', '8', '4', '6', '1', '10', '8', '4', '10', '4', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '6', '1', '5', '2', '9', '8', '5', '10', '8', '7', '9', '6', '4', '2', '6', '3', '8', '8', '9', '8', '2', '9', '10', '3', '10', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '5', '1', '4', '7', '6', '1', '10', '5', '4', '8', '4', '2', '7', '8', '1', '1', '7', '4', '1', '1', '9', '8', '6', '5', '9', '9', '3', '7', '6', '3', '10', '8', '10', '7', '2', '5', '1', '1', '9', '9', '5','20']
li.sort()
print(li)
```

output:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '20', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9']
```

I hope you get your answere.

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you:

```
a.sort(key=str)
```

or

```
new list = sorted(a, key=str) # if you dont want to change a
```

this will sort the list as you want even if the items are integer

Comment: thanks dear, let you know after putting it into action.

Comment: @PervezNawaz ok, Please check the green button if you find this answer helpful after your action.

Comment: dear, it didnt give expected result